# GitLab '404 Not Found' error when publishing a package using NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, gitlab

I encounter a `404 Not Found` error when attempting to publish a package to a package repository of a private/self-hosted instance of GitLab using NPM and GitLab's 'instance-level' scope/namespace configuration ([reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/#use-the-gitlab-endpoint-for-npm-packages)).

## Error

Executing `$ TOKEN=<ACCESS_TOKEN> npm publish` results in the following error:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/packages/npm/@org%2fpackage-1 - 404 Not Found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@org/package-1@0.1.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

## Configuration

My configuration of NPM is as follows:

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "@org/package-1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "peerDependencies": {
  },
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

*~/.npmrc*

```
@org:registry=https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/packages/npm/
//gitlab.example.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=$TOKEN

# @org/package-1
//gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/packages/npm/:_authToken=$TOKEN

# @org/package-2
//gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/packages/npm/:_authToken=$TOKEN

# @org/package-3
//gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/packages/npm/:_authToken=$TOKEN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

Add `publishConfig` to `package.json` with the URL of the GitLab package repository associated with the code repository.

*package.json (partial)*

```
"publishConfig": {
    "@org:registry": "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/packages/npm/"
},
```